# Lol won't start after update

Tags: games, playonlinux

I'm new to Ubuntu (running 16.04). I tried to install League of Legends through Play On Linux, and got it working after few install issues with mesa and tahoma32.

Once I updated the game and tried to run it through the launcher, it would just hang and not do anything.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with `playonlinux`, as the package is working perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04. The problem rests in your game's update. Try reinstalling your game and running it again.

Comment: You are welcome im just try to help good luck